# Change Wordpress Media Manager

Tags: images, uploads, media, file-manager

On the previous versions the media manager was like this

[image]

Newer Media Manager

[image]

My Question is How can i change to the older version media manager ??

Answer (score 1):

That's the same media manager.  The first image is what you see if you try to put a gallery into your page or post.  The second is what you will see if you add a Featured Image, where the gallery tab would not be relevant.

Comment: Why i am asking is that i have used 'media_upload_tabs' filter to add new tab. It is working on the first screenshot but not working on second screenshot. How can i display on the second screenshot ?? I need to add third tab and content of that tab on the second tab.

Comment: Ah, I see. That isn't the question you asked.  I'd suggest asking a more complete question including what you're trying to achieve and how you've tried to achieve it.  That should attract attention from folks who've coded tabs on the media manager.  I'm afraid that's an area of WP I haven't looked at myself though.